# Extracting data from the ul / li menu elements in DOMDocument

Tags: php

I have a list of menu items ol / li from which I want to extract data: TITLE, URL, TAGS and DESC from the specified class ol (items-3). I wrote a code that does not work, I can not deal with it, you have a hint of what I'm doing wrong?

**menu:**

```
<ol class="items-1">/*---*/</ol>
<ol class="items-2">/*---*/</ol>
<ol class="items-3">
  <li>
    <div class="title">[TITLE]</div>
    <a href="[URL]">
      <span class="tags">[TAGS]</span>
      <span class="desc">[DESC]</span>
      /*---*/
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">[TITLE]</div>
    <a href="[URL]">
      <span class="tags">[TAGS]</span>
      <span class="desc">[DESC]</span>
      /*---*/
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="title">[TITLE]</div>
    <a href="[URL]">
      <span class="tags">[TAGS]</span>
      <span class="desc">[DESC]</span>
      /*---*/
    </a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**script**

```
<?php
$html = '<ol class="items-1">/*---*/</ol>
    <ol class="items-2">/*---*/</ol>
    <ol class="items-3">
      <li>
        <div class="title">[TITLE]</div>
        <a href="[URL]">
          <span class="tags">[TAGS]</span>
          <span class="desc">[DESC]</span>
          /*---*/
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="title">[TITLE]</div>
        <a href="[URL]">
          <span class="tags">[TAGS]</span>
          <span class="desc">[DESC]</span>
          /*---*/
        </a>
      </li> </ol>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$ol = $dom->getElementsByTagName("ol")[2]; //for items-3 class
$li = $ol->getElementsByTagName("li");
foreach ($li as $element) {
    $title = $element->getElementsByTagName('div')->nodeValue;
    $url = $element->getElementsByTagName('a')->getAttribute('href');
    $tags = $element->getElementsByTagName('span')[0]->nodeValue;
    $desc = $element->getElementsByTagName('span')[1]->nodeValue;
}

?>
```

Thanks for all the help :) .

Comment: Please expand on 'does not work'...

Comment: Information is not extracted, message 505 is shown.

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) returns a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domnodelist.php). You have to tell php which one of the items you want to use.
Therefore the class DOMNodeList has the method [item()](http://php.net/manual/de/domnodelist.item.php), which returnes a [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domnode.php) via it's index in the NodeList.

For example change this

```
$title = $element->getElementsByTagName('div')->nodeValue;
```

to

```
$title = $element->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

The corrected code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$ol = $dom->getElementsByTagName("ol")->item(2); //for items-3 class
$li = $ol->getElementsByTagName("li");
foreach ($li as $element) {
    $title = $element->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $url = $element->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
    $tags = $element->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $desc = $element->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(1)->nodeValue;
}
```

working snippet: https://3v4l.org/6hcOt